# I want to show the invoiceitem table data in Yii2 view

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Here is my table in the database. I want to show it in the viewpage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at:datetime',
        // ...
    ],
]) ?>
```

Here is an explanation of what you need in order to make it work:

Assumming you have a controller, model, search model and view file:

(If you use gii (yii code generator) this code can all be generated for you (model, searchModel, controller and view).)

In your controller: (Yii2viewController.php)

(an action that handles the request)

```
public funtion actionYii2view()
{
 $searchModel = new InvoiceitemSearch();
 $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

 return $this->render('yii2view', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        ]);
}
```

In your view file: (yii2view.php)
(gridview which echos out your table data)

```
     <?= GridView::widget([
                    'id' => "projectsGridView",
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 
                    'columns' => [
                    'unit_code_master_id',
                    'qty',
                    'is_include_tax',
                    ...
                    'line_total_amt'
    ]]); ?>
```

Add a comment if something is unclear.

In future questions please describe what you tried and any errors you came across in your efforts.